# Coyoneda hasn't a higher-rank type but what type has it actually?

Tags: haskell, gadt, newtype, higher-rank-types

`Yoneda` has a valid type as long as the higher-rank extension is set:

`newtype Yoneda f a = Yoneda (forall b. (a -> b) -> f b)` which yields the type `(forall b. (a -> b) -> f b) -> Yoneda f a`.

`b` is picked by the consumer of `Yoneda` and hence doesn't appear on the LHS of the `newtype` declaration.

`Coyoneda`, however, doesn't make sense to me:

`data Coyoneda f a = forall b. Coyoneda (b -> a) (f b)` which yields `(b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a`.

`b` is explicitly quantified but the quantifier doesn't seem to be in the right position to render the type variable rank 2. Nonetheless `b` isn't listed on the LHS of the `data` declaration. So what is it? Almost existential? This is only an uneducated guess, because I don't quite understand existential quantifiers and assume Haskell doesn't support them.

Comment: It's indeed an existential. Haskell has some support for them, even if it has no `exists` keyword.

Comment: See the [`ExistentialQuantification`](https://ghc.gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/doc/users_guide/exts/existential_quantification.html#extension-ExistentialQuantification) documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
data Coyoneda f a = forall b. Coyoneda (b -> a) (f b)
```

Can also be written with GADT syntax:

```
data Coyoneda f a where
  Coyoneda :: forall b. (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a
```

The explicit quantification is optional.

```
Coyoneda ::               (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a
Coyoneda :: forall f a b. (b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a
```

So you got it right: `b` is existentially quantified here, since it doesn’t appear in the result type of the `Coyoneda` data constructor.

Comment: The effect of existential quantification seems to be contained within the data declaration, i.e. has no effect outside of it, b/c `(b -> a) -> f b -> Coyoneda f a` seems to be just a normal, standard HM type. If I pass `id` , for instance, `b -> a` is simply unified with `a -> a` without any special treatment for `b`, right?

Comment: @IvenMarquart, when you pattern match on the constructor, you get a fresh type you can capture using `ScopedTypeVariables`. `f (Coyoneda g (b :: b)) = ...`. Also importantly, you can't pattern match lazily on `Coyoneda`, so `let Coyoneda f x = blah in bloop` is an error.

Comment: @IvenMarquardt: If you’re more comfortable with a universal than an existential here, you can relate the two by `unCoyoneda :: Coyoneda f a -> (forall b. (b -> a) -> f b -> r) -> r`. The type variable `b` cannot appear in the “result” type `r` of the consumer, because it would escape its scope. Alternatively, you can think of an existential as a pair of a type, here `b`, with a value that depends on that type, here equivalent to `(b -> a, f b)`.

Comment: @JonPurdy Ya, I need it for the type validator I work on, which doesn't support existentials in data constructors. CPS is almost always a solution but harder to work with. I'll explore the pair representation. Thanks, this was really helpful!